# Show other command line prompt in Midnight Commander (mc)

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt, ps1, midnight-commander

Is it possible to have different command line prompt in pure `bash` and `mc`? So, sometime i have `mc` started, but but panels switched off (Ctrl+O), and when i return back to the terminal after some period of time I forget is `mc` started or not, and some times try to start `mc` again, or try to switch on panels, when `mc` is not started.

So, what I try to do: in normal mode path should look like:

```
PS1=\u@\h:\w$
```

when in `mc` mode something like:

```
PS1=mc \u:\w$
```

So, the question is: **how can i make different `PS1` prompts for `mc` and pure `bash`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man mc` says:

> If you are using bash you can specify startup commands for the
>   subshell in your  `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc`  file  and  special
>   keyboard maps in the `~/.local/share/mc/inputrc file`.  tcsh users may
>   specify startup commands in the `~/.local/share/mc/tcshrc` file.

So you can set up your different version of `PS1` variable inside `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc`.

Comment: found it, thanks. shame on me: i missed it in man, and i've tried already ~/.config/mc, ~/.mc and bunch of other places, but i missed only one right place for "shell specific settings"